# Pipeline pattern implementation in java

Tags: java, performance, design-patterns, language-agnostic

read about Pipeline pattern from [here](http://parlab.eecs.berkeley.edu/wiki/_media/patterns/pipeline-v1.pdf)

how to implement pipeline pattern in java?

is there any open source java project that uses pipeline pattern?

Comment: The paper you link to already lists variants and applications in great detail...

Comment: i was looking for applications other than signal/image processing. know any java implementations?

Comment: Well, none of that is obvious from your question. If you expect serious, good answers, then please take the effort to post a serious, unambiguous question.

Comment: Wow... that "paper" is pretty much a carbon copy of the "Pipeline pattern" chapter from [Patterns for Parallel Programming (Mattson et al)](http://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Parallel-Programming-Timothy-Mattson/dp/0321228111)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are looking for a specific task processing component or just pipelining software in general. However, [JBoss Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) implements a pipeline pattern for attaching and detaching IO processors. It's really intended for NIO based networking stacks (although it does have a local component). Perhaps this will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding

> how to implement pipeline pattern in java?

I think you could use [Apache commons-chain](http://commons.apache.org/chain/), that is geared to this right?

Comment: does chain of responsibility useful for parallel processing?