# How to create abstract Function using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

I am trying to implement a pipeline design pattern using Java 8 with the below article for my reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713936/4770397

Code:

```
public abstract class Pipeline{
Function<Integer, Integer> addOne = it -> {
        System.out.println(it + 1);
        return it + 1;
    };

Function<Integer, Integer> addTwo = it -> {
        System.out.println(it + 2);
        return it + 2;
    };

Function<Integer, Integer> timesTwo = input -> {
        System.out.println(input * 2);
        return input * 2;
    };

final Function<Integer, Integer> pipe = sourceInt
    .andThen(timesTwo)
    .andThen(addOne)
    .andThen(addTwo);
}
```

I am trying to add one abstract method & want to override it.
I am trying to do something like:

```
abstract BiFunction<Integer, Integer,Integer> overriden;
```

and change pipe to:

```
final Function<Integer, Integer> pipe = sourceInt
    .andThen(timesTwo)
    .andThen(overriden)
    .andThen(addOne)
    .andThen(addTwo);
}
```

But the problem is, I don't know to declare a `Function<Integer, Integer>` as an abstract method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just declare a regular abstract method that takes an `Integer` and returns an `Integer` and use the method reference syntax to refer to it:

```
public abstract Integer overridden(Integer input);

final Function<Integer, Integer> pipe = sourceInt
    .andThen(timesTwo)
    .andThen(this::overridden)
    .andThen(addOne)
    .andThen(addTwo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, instead of 1 parameter how can I pass 2 parameters?

Comment: @mayankbisht Are you looking for [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html)?

Comment: @Sweeper- yes I am looking for BiFunction.

Comment: @mayankbisht all the time, when you wrote lines similar to `Function<Integer, Integer> timesTwo = input -> {...};`, that signified accepting one parameter and the question never mentioned anything about passing 2 parameters. Do make an edit for what you intend to ask or else the questions are merely lost.

Comment: @Naman - Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated the question.

Comment: Hope @Sweeper would update the answer soon as well. But the concept as highlighted currently could very well remain the same.

Comment: @mayankbisht You see, now the pipeline you wrote doesn't really make sense. `sourceInt.andThen(timesTwo)` is a `Function<Integer, Integer>`, so it will produce _one_ integer as its output. You are trying to somehow connect that to a function that accepts _two_ inputs. Do you see the problem here? Where should the other parameter for `overridden` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Fields aren't a subject to polymorphism - you need a method. You either write

1. a method that just returns a `Function<Integer, Integer>` instance

   ```
   public abstract Function<Integer, Integer> getMyFunction();
   ```
2. a method that actually represents a `Function<Integer, Integer>`

   ```
   public abstract Integer myFunction(Integer i);
   ```

and then do

```
.andThen(getMyFunction())
```

or

```
.andThen(i -> myFunction(i))
// .andThen(this::myFunction) // fancier
```

respectively.

For example,

```
interface I {
  Function<Integer, Integer> getFunction();
  Integer function(Integer i);
}

class A implements I {
  @Override
  public Function<Integer, Integer> getFunction() {
    return i -> i + 1;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer function(Integer i) {
    return i + 1;
  }
}

class B implements I {
  @Override
  public Function<Integer, Integer> getFunction() {
    return i -> i * 2;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer function(Integer i) {
    return i * 2;
  }
}

class T {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    Function<Integer, Integer> f1 = a.getFunction().andThen(b.getFunction());
    System.out.println(f1.apply(2)); // 6

    Function<Integer, Integer> f2 = a.getFunction().andThen(b::function);
    System.out.println(f2.apply(2)); // 6

    Function<Integer, Integer> f3 = ((Function<Integer, Integer>)a::function).andThen(b::function);
    System.out.println(f3.apply(2)); // 6
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, instead of 1 parameter how can I pass 2 parameters?